# SmoothDivScroll - changing opacity of overflow content instead of hiding it

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

My first question on stack overflow.

I am using this fantastic jquery library for scrolling content http://www.smoothdivscroll.com. Just wanted to know if it is possible to have overflow content visible in a lower opacity like [BBC Home Page](http://www.bbc.co.uk) instead of being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

I can't see this on BBC's homepage though? Have they redesigned since you posted this?

There's no built in support for lowering the opacity of overflow content. But you could try making the scroller longer than you need and modify the CSS for the hot spots so they cover the left and right edges of the scroller giving the impression of the content fading out on either side. If you don't want hot spots, you could try positioning other (semi transparent) elements on top of the scroller at the left and right edge to create the same effect.

But all in all - it's up to the web developer to implement any special design like this.

Good luck!